# I can't create a new partition bigger than 1 MiB

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I made the mistake of not partitioning my hdd before installing Ubuntu, and now it doesn't let me create a new partition bigger than 1 MiB, nor can I resize the boot partition. Does anyone know what to do?. 
[GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtwI9.png)

Comment: From your picture; the 1MiB is all that unused; all other space was already allocated to sda1.  You cannot reduce size of sda1 because it's currently mounted, you need to `umount` first, but using a 'live' system is far easier (ie. use your install media)

Comment: I can't. It says that the drive is busy. What's a live media? (Sorry, I literally installed Linux yesterday)

Comment: You cannot reduce size of sda1 because it's currently mounted, you need to `umount` first, but using a 'live' system is far easier (ie. use your install media).  (*I said that already I know, but if you're trying to `umount`, you need to first kill everything that is using it...   why I suggested the 'live' system is far easier; booting it and using 'try ubuntu'*)

Comment: Right. Every time I try booting from the USB drive, it boots and when I go to gparted, it says that the HDD is still mounted. Should I just disconnect the hdd before booting? (The USB drive I have now is just 4gb). Do yo know any way to do this on windows without wiping the drives?

Comment: No you should not disconnect your drive when booting the 'live' media; however you've not provided any release information (newer releases use swap files so won't automatically create a swap partition on hdd/ssd, however older releases will do this so you should disable/umount the swap before changing partition size if the swap partition is in the way). We can only go by information you provide, and we don't have release information (what your install [release] was originally (ie. whether swap partition was created by default), what it is now , and what 'live' media you are using..)

Comment: I already managed to create the second partition. But I don't know how to make it to show up for me to transfer son files into it. (I'm running 18.04 LTS)

Comment: You might be best creating a new question for that (it doesn't fit your existing question at all), but I'd create an entry in the file system table (`/etc/fstab`) mounting wherever you want it so it auto-mounts every boot like your '/' partition does.   I'd get the UUID from `blkid` and use your '/' entry as guide; but what the entry could vary on where you are mounting it, details we do not have.  If you `mount` over a partition on '/' dirs won't be merged; the later will `mount` over the first hiding all files in first, thus setup using 'live' is easiest.. Depends on where you choose..